Color issues when viewing photos in irfanview
Recently got a new computer and downloaded irfanview on it but now some of my images don't display colors properly now even though they did fine on my old computer with irfanview. Some of the photos appear very dull/washed out even though I know they aren't because they show up normal on any other image viewing program (win photos, gimp, photoshop, browsers). This is only an issue on a select few images, all the rest of them display normally.

I've already installed all of the plugins and then enabled color management in settings and checked the box saying "apply also for images without embedded color profile".

While it's good to have a broad range of questions and answers here, I have a feeling that this actually rather belongs on the Irfanview forum... IrfanView Support Forum

I planned on doing that originally but it won't let me make a post even after making an account and that's how I ended up here...

This desaturated effect usually occurs when an image is in a wide gamut color space like ProphotoRGB or AdobeRGB and it is erroneously assigned the sRGB color space (due to lack of embedded color space info).
I would open it in photoshop where it opens correctly and save a copy, ensuring the "convert to sRGB" and "embed color space" options are enabled; then see how irfanview does with it.

Have you profiled the monitor(s) on your new system?  If there's no screen profiles color management probably isn't working correctly.

I don't think that's quite right. An uncalibrated monitor would be liable to show colour-managed images incorrectly regardless of the viewing application. It's not going to be the cause of some applications displaying images differently to others.

@osullic most applications aren't color managed and are going to treat all images as being in the display gamut.  An app with a misconfigured CMS can do something like treat the screen as being in the working color space, with a wide-gamut working space and automatic conversion of profiled images to that working space.
It's implied that this is an enhanced version of irfanview with color management so I suspect this is a problem that only appears when color managed.

I think you are overly convoluting the situation. I understand colour management. The OP says that the images appear correctly in gimp and photoshop, but not in irfanview. It doesn't seem likely to me that this is an issue with monitor calibration.
